# Add DIVs and remove them clicking on a link?

Tags: jquery, html

Using a select dropdown list and `$(code).appendTo('#mydiv');` I'm able to add the html code stored in variable "code" (looks like `<div>...</div>` just before the end of `div` mydiv.

Now in the DIVs added this way, I would like to create a link (the (-) in the attached image

[image: http://www.sportplus.ch/racetracking/printscreen-add-remove-div.gif]

used to remove the corresponding div when clicked.

Of course the number of `div`s to be should be limited and I do not allow to add twice the same number.

As the `div`s are not available when page is loaded, I cannot define a event on the not yet existing links. I found the `.live()` feature which seems to be a clue. Now I need to find a way to detect which link (-) is clicked in order to remove the right `div`.

I cannot figure out how to achieve the last point.
Can someone help me here?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Please post the relevant html structure of the `div`s, and their children. And a live demo, at [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/), or [JS Bin](http://jsbin.com/), would go a long way to helping us help you.

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this:

```
$('.link').live('click',function(){
    $(this).parent().remove();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Given you haven't posted the relevant html, I can only make assumptions. But the following will work:

```
$('.removeLink').live('click',
    function(){
        $(this).closest('div.dynamicallyAddedDiv').remove();
    });
```

This will, of course, only remove the `div` belonging to the class-name of 'dynamicallyAddedDiv.'

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/FkZSy/).